# Grab dynamic input value in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

This is my form view:

[image: My form]

and this is my dynamic input form code:

```
  ...
  let subJudulInput = []; // this variable will render
  for (var i = 0; i < this.props.subtitleInput.index; i++) {
     let index = i + 1;
     subJudulInput.push(
        <div key={'formgroup' + index} class="form-group">
           {(i === 0) ? <label for="subJudulInput">Sub Judul</label>:false}
           <input key={'input' + index} type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={`Masukan Sub Judul ${index}`}/>
        </div>
     );
  }
  ...
```

If I click the plus button, the new input form will show:

This is my form handler:

```
onAddingTitle(event) { // if the submit button get pressed
      let formData = {subJudul:[]};
      event.preventDefault();

      console.log(event.target.elements);

   }
```

How I can grab all of that dynamic input value? *(Best ways)* to formData object; like this:

```
let formData = {subJudul:[
   'sub judul 1 value here',
   'sub judul 2 value here',
   'sub judul 3 value here',
   'next new input'
]};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `name` attribute to the text field: `name={"textbox-"+index}`

Try the below code to get your expected values

```
    onAddingTitle(event) { 
      event.preventDefault();
    let formElements = event.target.elements;
    let formData = {
      subJudul: []
    };
    Object.keys(formElements).forEach((key) => {
      if (formElements[key].type == 'text') {
        formData.subJudul.push(formElements[key].value)
      }
    });
    console.log('formData', formData);
   }
```

Explanation:

- Get the form elements (which is a object)
- loop through the object elemets using keys
- Check the type of the field, if its a textbox(add as per your need) push the value of the field to array.

Comment: the expression in if statement returned double data in formData... i just changed it to: if (key.search('textbox') != -1) and it works... thanks anyway. :)